# bootstrap datepicker setDate format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have to set the date in my datepicker in dd/mm/yyyy format. Whet I'm trying to do, with Javascript is this:

```
  var year = 2014;
  var month = 5;
  var day = 10;

  var realDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day); // months are 0-based!

  $('#MainContent_txtDataConsegna').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' }); // format to show
  $('#MainContent_txtDataConsegna').datepicker('setDate', realDate);
```

the problem is that the value inside my datepicker is always in format mm/dd/yyyy. Where is the problem??

Here the definition datepicker and datepicker options:

```
   <div class="input-group date">
       <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDataOrdine" class="form-control" onBlur="CalcolaTotaliTestata('txtDataOrdine')"></asp:TextBox>
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>/span>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
       todayBtn: "linked",
       language: "it",
       autoclose: true,
       todayHighlight: true,
       dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' 
   });
</script>
```

Comment: I noticed when we use jquery its `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'`, and for pure javascript use `format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Change

```
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
```

to

```
format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
```

Looks like you just misread some documentation!

Comment: As there is other answer, for some of us works format: 'dd/mm/yyyy' and for other dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'. The simplest way to solve this is just to try which name is supported.

Comment: @Krystian Same for me: `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'`.

Answer (score 17):

Changing to `format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'` didn't work for me, and changing that to `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'` added year multiple times, The finest one for me was,

```
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
```

Comment: I also had to use the 'dateFormat' option rather than 'format' to get this to work.

I think there must be a bug in v1.6.1 because I had this problem where 'dd/mm/yyyy' duplicated the year value when you made a selection from the calendar. Switching it to 'dd/mm/yy' worked but is not the correct format as it displays the four digit year while the format suggests it shoud only be showing two.

Comment: For en-US culture, `m/dd/yy` worked and for other culture, `dd/mm/yy` worked fine.

Comment: This worked for me in bootstrap-datepicker v1.7.1.  It seems to be a bug, let me know if it was solved in later versions, thanks.

Answer (score 15):

a bit change in format

format : "DD/MM/YYYY"

Answer (score 15):

There is confusing when you are using data picker, for bootstrap datepicker you have to use following code:-

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
   format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
```

and for jquery datepicker following code must be used:-

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
       dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
```

So you must be aware which date picker you are using, that is ultimately solve your issue, Hope this hepls you.

Comment: This a very common confusion among developers so be alert after using datepickers.

Answer (score 8):

for me it is daterangepicker worked by this :

```
     $('#host1field').daterangepicker({
                   locale: {
                            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
                            }
                 });
```

Comment: I think this is the newest correct answer

Comment: It's worked. This is the latest solution.

Answer (score 3):

For Me i got same issue i resolved like this 
changed 
format:'dd/mm/yy'
to
 **dateFormat**: 'dd/mm/yy'

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code for bootstrap datepicker:

**HTML Code:**

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datepicker"></p>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
   format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

format : "DD/MM/YYYY" should resolve your issue. If you need more help regarding available formats, please visit http://momentjs.com/ which is used by this control internally.

I was facing an issue where this "format" thing was working fine on local machine but when I deployed the application on server, the date was not getting populated and the control was empty. when I commented the format code, it started working but then I didn't have the format that I needed. I fixed that issue using globalization entries in web.config.

```
<system.web>
    <globalization
    requestEncoding="utf-8"
    responseEncoding="utf-8"
    culture="en-GB"
    uiCulture="en-GB" />    
</system.web>
```

This helped in ensuring that both local & server environments have same culture.

Answer (score 2):

> "As with bootstrap’s own plugins, datepicker provides a data-api that can be used to instantiate datepickers without the need for custom javascript..."

[Boostrap DatePicker Documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

**Maybe you want to set format without DatePicker instance**, for that, you have to add the property `data-date-format="DateFormat"` to main Div tag, for example:

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>

    <input type="text" name="YourName" id="YourId" class="YourClass">
</div>
```

Comment: This one worked for me while none of the above did. Thanks @LuisEduardox

Answer (score 2):

This line of code works for me

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
```

you can change the id **#datepicker** with the class **.input-group.date** of course

Answer (score 1):

I have some problems with jquery mobile 1.4.5. For example it seems accepting format change only passing from "option". And there are some refresh problem with the calendar using "option". For all that have the same problems I can suggest this code:

```
$( "#mydatepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy" );
$( "#mydatepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", new Date());    
$('.ui-datepicker-calendar').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A'
```

As we all know JS is case-sensitive.
So this will display

10/05/2016 12:00 AM

In your case is

```
format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
```

Display : 10/05/2016

My bootstrap datetimepicker is based on 
[eonasdan bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

As with bootstrap’s own plugins, datepicker provides a data-api that can be used to instantiate datepickers without the need for custom javascript..
Use this for Bootstrap:

```
<label>Date of Birth</label>
<input name="userdob" data-provide="datepicker" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" date-autoclose="true" class="form-control courtdata" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this worked.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: new Date() // disabling past dates
});
```