# I am using datepicker for calender, but it works good for mm/dd/yyyy, but i want it in dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: jquery, date, datetime, datepicker

I am using datepicker for calender, but it works good for mm/dd/yyyy.

And not working for dd/mm/yyyy format.. how can do it in dd/mm/yyyy format??

Code Snippet:

```
var newAvaDateForm = "28/07/2017";

var plusNintyDays = "25/10/2017";

$('#date1').datepicker({
   format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', 
   minDate:newAvaDateForm,
   maxDate:plusNintyDays,
   autoclose:1
});
```

Now my project on live mode.. i cant change plugin.

so many operations on that calender.

so please suggest me how to change it in dd/mm/yyyy format??

Also changed "format" to "dateFormat".. though its not working??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bootstrap datepicker setDate format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725988/bootstrap-datepicker-setdate-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Use lowercase in your format string and will be happy! See [documentation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format) for details.

Comment: change format to dateformat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQueryUI.DatePicker How to change Date in format dd/mm/yyyy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605133/jqueryui-datepicker-how-to-change-date-in-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat).

You need to pass the key as `dateFormat`, and the format is also invalid. Try this:

```
$('#date1').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
   minDate:newAvaDateForm,
   maxDate:plusNintyDays,
   autoclose:1
});
```

Comment: changed format to dateFormat.. though its not working??

Comment: @AmolPatil - I updated my answer. `yy` gives a 4 digit year, I thought it was `yyyy`. Can you retry?

Answer (score 0):

Change `format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',` to `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',`. This will allow you to display date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

```js
var newAvaDateForm = "28/07/2017";
var plusNintyDays = "25/10/2017";

$('#date1').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
   minDate:newAvaDateForm,
   maxDate:plusNintyDays,
   autoclose:1
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
Date: <input type="text" id="date1">
```

Comment: Glad, it helped you. :)